# Getting exit message from one python script when called from another master script

Tags: python, subprocess, exit, sys

I have a master python script which uses `subprocess.check_call` to run another couple of smaller scripts.

I do not want to see the output of these smaller scripts so I am using `stdout=DEVNULL`

I can get the `returncode` by catching `CalledProcessError` but i'd like to catch the message passed, if the script ends with say `sys.exit('my exit message')`

I can't seem to catch that message though - is this even possible in Python? I'd prefer not to have to write to a file to read the exit message.

This is what I have tried in my `master.py`:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_call('python scripttoberun.py', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.args)
    print(e.output)
    print(e.stderr)
    print(e.returncode)
    print(e.cmd)
```

and in my `scripttoberun.py`:

```
import sys
print('starting... ')
sys.exit('im quitting')
```

but I cannot seem to catch the `'im quitting` message?

I can only see this output:

```
(1, 'python scripttoberun.py')
None
None
1
python scripttoberun.py
```

Is this possible?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get this to work, I had to pass the `stderr=PIPE` parameter to the `check_output` function. Then by using `.decode()` on the `stderr` exception I can get the message. Perfecto

Here is my code in `master.py`:

```
from subprocess import check_output, CalledProcessError, PIPE

try:
    check_output('python scripttoberun.py', stderr=PIPE)
    print('Program ran successfully')
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print('Program did not run successfully: ', e.stderr.decode())
```